# copy from another sqlite table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, sql-update, subquery

I have a sqlite database with two tables.
The first table (Raport_luna) contain two columns (user and in_Arbeit_ohne_AT ) and the second table(sqlite_sequence) contain two columns (seq and name).
I want to copy the values from seq(sqlite_sequence) to  in_Arbeit_ohne_AT (Raport_luna) where Raport_luna.user=sqlite_sequence.name but I have errors at the 'FROM' line.

This is my code:

```
UPDATE Raport_luna 
SET in_Arbeit_ohne_AT = sqlite_sequence.seq
FROM sqlite_sequence WHERE  Raport_luna.user=sqlite_sequence.name;
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQLite, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
update raport_luna r
set in_Arbeit_ohne_at = (select s.seq from sqlite_sequence s where s.name = r.user)
```

If there may be "missing" names in the source table, and you don't want to set the corresponding column to `null` in the target table, you can add a `where` condition:

```
update raport_luna r
set in_Arbeit_ohne_at = (select s.seq from sqlite_sequence s where s.name = r.user)
where exists (select 1 from sqlite_sequence s where s.name = r.user)
```